# Prestashop make address2 field required

Tags: prestashop, checkout

On [www.loulou.ro](http://www.loulou.ro/) I have the **One page checkout for Prestashop Module** installed. The Prestashop version is 1.5.

The shop has only one payment option (Cash on Delivery). I want the second address field - labeled "Judet/Sector" - to be required.

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your site backoffice `Customers` > `Addresses` tab and at the page bottom press `Set required fields for this section` button. There you can make your changes.

**Prestashop 1.5**

[image: Customers Addresses tab in Prestashop 1.5]

**Prestashop 1.6**

[image: Customers Addresses tab in Prestashop 1.6]

Comment: How can I do that in Prestashop version is 1.5? Thank you!

Comment: There is the same way for the Prestashop 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: I also get this error: POST http://www.loulou.ro/adresa?back=order-opc.php 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: I see many errors in your site, I guess you have edited some files manually, so there can be many reasons for the error 500... Try to return to the default site files as much as possible.